# I have a column that is still showing null even when I check to see if it is null

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL Query below:

```
SELECT c.COURT_ID, ci.BODY_TEXT
,  TYPE = (
         SELECT 
         CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Courts of Appeals' THEN 'appellate court'
         WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'District Courts' THEN 'special trial court'
         WHEN DESCRIPTION IS NULL OR c.FINE_ID IS NULL THEN 'legislative court'
         ELSE DESCRIPTION
         END
         FROM [STAGING].COURT_LOCATION
         WHERE c.FINE_ID = FINE_ID)   
FROM [STAGING].[COURT] c
LEFT OUTER JOIN [STAGING].COURT_INFO ci on c.COURT_ID = ci.COURT_ID
```

Sometimes `TYPE` column will show as NULL.

When it is NULL, the `c.FINE_ID` column is also NULL.

So when `TYPE` is NULL, I want it to default to `legislative court`.

So I made a `CASE` statement that checks both `DESCRIPTION` from the `[STAGING].COURT_LOCATION` table and `c.FINE_ID` from the `[COURT]` table.

I don't get any errors, but it still shows NULL for `TYPE` when `FINE_ID` is NULL.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem null doesn't equal null, so `WHERE c.FINE_ID = FINE_ID` is not true when FINE_ID is null.

The simplest fix is to use [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT c.COURT_ID, ci.BODY_TEXT
,  TYPE = COALESCE(
         (SELECT 
         CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'Courts of Appeals' THEN 'appellate court'
         WHEN DESCRIPTION = 'District Courts' THEN 'special trial court'
         WHEN DESCRIPTION IS NULL OR c.FINE_ID IS NULL THEN 'legislative court'
         ELSE DESCRIPTION
         END
         FROM [STAGING].COURT_LOCATION
         WHERE c.FINE_ID = FINE_ID), 'legislative court') 
FROM [STAGING].[COURT] c
LEFT OUTER JOIN [STAGING].COURT_INFO ci on c.COURT_ID = ci.COURT_ID
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but get this error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: I think you just need an extra parentheses. `TYPE = COALESCE((SELECT...`

Comment: @JNevill thx. Yep I missed the opening bracket. Fixed now (I think)

Answer (score 2):

Because the CASE expression is inside the subquery and your subquery is in your SELECT clause, that subquery is acting as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so when the condition in your subquery's WHERE clause fails, you get a `NULL`. In other words, there is no record in your subquery for that particular `FILE_ID` and so there is no result from the case expression that can be brought through to your main query, you just get `NULL`.

Instead, properly join the `COURT_LOCATION` table in your FROM clause and do the CASE expression directly in your SELECT.

```
SELECT c.COURT_ID, ci.BODY_TEXT
, 
         CASE WHEN cl.DESCRIPTION = 'Courts of Appeals' THEN 'appellate court'
         WHEN cl.DESCRIPTION = 'District Courts' THEN 'special trial court'
         WHEN cl.DESCRIPTION IS NULL THEN 'legislative court'
         ELSE cl.DESCRIPTION
         END as Type         
FROM [STAGING].[COURT] c
LEFT OUTER JOIN [STAGING].COURT_LOCATION cl 
    ON c.FINE_ID = cl.FINE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [STAGING].COURT_INFO ci on c.COURT_ID = ci.COURT_ID
```